# ElementRef in Angular@2.0.0-beta.0 and Angular@ElementRef 2.0.0-beta.1

Tags: angular

I tried to update angular2.0.0-beta0 to angular 2.0.0-beta 1 and I got a problem when use elementRef. In Beta0, everything perfect!

```
constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private elementRef: ElementRef, 
    private renderer: Renderer, ds: SaleDataService, 
    private ticketDataSelection: TicketDataSelection, private z: NgZone) {}
```

```
load() {
  if (this.selectedTicketTab == 0) {
    this.dynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(childComponet,
              this.elementRef, "childComponents")
      .then((r) => {
        this.instances.push(r);
        this.isPayment = r.instance.payment;
      });
```

but when update beta1. I debug inside, too many thing changed :(. And i got this error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: There is no component directive at element [object Object]

Comment: A repro would be awesome ;)

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6543

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6543

The renderer now takes native elements instead of ElementsRefs.

I.e. use `renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement...)`
…

Comment: Why does the  `private` in `private elementRef: ElementRef` is mandatory ?

Comment: It implicitely creates a private field and assigns the passes value to it (`public` and `protected` as well). This way you have ro write less code.